# EWS Managed API: How to work with calendars (create, update, delete, get)

Tags: exchangewebservices, office365

I need to create, update, delete and get calendars for all users in domain.
Is it possible to it using EWS Managed API?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Please read what's [on-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for Stack Overflow.

Comment: I think it is rather concrete question. I'd like to create/update/delete/get calendars using EWS Managed API. I want to know is it possible.

Comment: Hi Andrei,  Have you taken a look at https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Exchange-2013-101-Code-3c38582c ?  This set of code samples should have what you are looking for.  If you are targeting Office 365, we recommend you use our REST API.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/APi/calendar-rest-operations for more info.  Thanks.

Comment: @AndreiKolesnikovich: You wrote that you want us to _find a link_. That is off-topic. If you want something else, then why do you ask for it?

Comment: @honk: OK, I'll reformulate my answer, to avoid off-topic

Comment: @Venkat Ayyadevara: REST API doesn't support impersonation, but I'm need to work with calendars of all users in domain.

Comment: @AndreiKolesnikovich: You seem to have done some research, because you can already exclude the REST API. This is important context information and you should put it directly into the question. One-line questions have the tendency to get downvoted. Currently it looks as if you are too lazy to read the EWS documentation. Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) to learn what we expect from questions and then [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/27780009/edit) your post in order to improve it.

Answer (score 0):

As Venkat says, we recommend REST if you're targeting Office 365. If not, EWS can work with calendars. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn495623(v=exchg.150).aspx